# Polymorphic relationship with pivot data

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I would like to solve the following issue:

I got multiple models like:

- `Product`
- `Customer`

Each model should be able to have one or more `Fields` with pivot data.

`Field`:

- `id`
- `title`
- `type`
- `required`

**Example:**

`Product` has a field called `video_url`, `type` should be `string` containing the `pivot` value `http://youtube.com/...`.

`Customer` has a field called `external_id`, `type` should be `integer` containing the `pivot` value `242`.

The fields should be added dynamically by the user. The user should be able to decide, whether the field is morphing to `Product` or `Customer` (or even more later).

Maybe this helps to understand:

[image]

**What I am doing right now**

At the moment I created a new Model for each, `product` and `customer`

For customers:

```
class CustomerField extends Model
{
    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\belongsToMany
     */
    public function customers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Customer::class)->withPivot('value');
    }
}
```

For products:

```
class ProductField extends Model
{
    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\belongsToMany
     */
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)->withPivot('value');
    }
}
```

At the moment this works out, but of course, it's not the most elegant way to solve it.

**My question**

Is there a possibility to morph a field dynamically to `Product` or `Customer` with an additional `pivot`?

Comment: i dont understand what you want to do exactly, do you have an exact table setup?

Comment: I added a picture of what I'd like to archive. At the moment I do not have a working table setup.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this is what you want [Polymorphic:Many-to-Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations)

You don't need to add `ProductField` and `CustomerField` models,

you just need to add `Product`, `Customer` and `Field` model.

The fields will **dynamically belongs to product or customer by** `fieldable_type`. Even you have more models, it will store the model name to this `fieldable_type`.

And the tables you need to be created like this below:

[image]

`fieldables` table has `fieldable_id` and `fieldable_type`;

`fieldable_type` will set your model name automatically, like `App\Product`, and you can custom that by yourself in `AppServiceProvider`:

```php
Relation::morphMap([
    'products' => 'App\Product',
    'customers' => 'App\Customer',
]);
```

#### In Product Model:

```php
class Product extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the fields for the product.
     */
    public function fields()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('App\Field', 'fieldable')->withPivot('value');
    }
}
```

#### In Customer Model:

```php
class Customer extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the fields for the customer.
     */
    public function fields()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('App\Field', 'fieldable')->withPivot('value');
    }
}
```

#### In Field Model:

```php
class Field extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the products that are assigned this field.
     */
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Product', 'fieldable');
    }

    /**
     * Get all of the customers that are assigned this field.
     */
    public function customers()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Customer', 'fieldable');
    }
}
```

### CRUD with Pivot Value:

After that, you can easily create, get, update, delete pivot value like:

```php
Field::first()->products; # return the products with pivot value
Field::first()->customers; # return the customers with pivot value
Customer::first()->fields;

$field = Field::first();
# create new relationship with pivot value between customer and fields:
Customer::first()->fields()->attach($field, ['value' => 'customer new value field']);
# update pivot with value:
Customer::first()->fields()->sync([$field->id => ['value' => 'update customer value field']]);
# Delete pivot
Customer::first()->fields()->detach($field->id);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to use a separate table to hold meta information so that you can easily add/remove "columns" as needed

For example, you could set your meta table up like this:

```
create table `ProductField` (
    products_id int(11),
    column_name varchar(255),
    value varchar(255),
)
```

Then in your products model, add functionality to get, insert, check if exists, etc.

```
public function getMeta($column) {
    $meta =  DB::table('ProductField ')
        ->select('column_name', 'value')
        ->where('products_id', '=', $this->id)
        ->where('column_name', '=', $column)
        ->get();

    if (!$meta->isEmpty()) {
        return $meta;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

public function addMeta($column, $value) {
    DB::table('ProductField ')->insert(
       [
        'products_id' => $this->id,
        'column_name' => $column, 
        'value' => $value,
       ]
    );
}
```

The same way you can achieve dynamic nature for Customers too.

You can also use an array to store the feilds and then dynamically add them to the model

```
foreach ($request->input('cost') as $key=>$cost) {

    Price::create([
        'product_id' => $request->product_id[$key],
        'date' => Carbon::now(),
        'cost' => $cost,
        'trend' => 0
    ]);
}
```

If you know that there will only be certain dynamic fields ahead of time, you could opt to create [accessor methods](https://www.amitmerchant.com/fetching-dynamic-attributes-models-laravel/) for them